# Can I make this query more concise and easier to read?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL server query where I was needed to access information by columns, which produced a very long case statement to cover all necessary columns.

I was wondering if there is a more concise and easy to read way to construct this query without taking from the functionality.

One approach that came to mind is to use a pivot table, but I had some trouble in fully understanding how to implement it.

The query:

```
SELECT
        @priceToPay =
        SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN @numDaysChosen = 1 THEN CASE
                    WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                        tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price1DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                    ELSE CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                                YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price1DayInWeek, tcd.Price) * @percentToCalc
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price1DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                                    ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price1DayInWeek, tcd.Price) / 2
                                END
                            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price1DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                        END
                END
            WHEN @numDaysChosen = 2 THEN CASE
                    WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                        tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price2DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                    ELSE CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                                YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price2DayInWeek, tcd.Price) * @percentToCalc
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price2DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                                    ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price2DayInWeek, tcd.Price) / 2
                                END
                            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price2DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                        END
                END
            WHEN @numDaysChosen = 3 THEN CASE
                    WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                        tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price3DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                    ELSE CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                                YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price3DayInWeek, tcd.Price) * @percentToCalc
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price3DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                                    ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price3DayInWeek, tcd.Price) / 2
                                END
                            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price3DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                        END
                END
            WHEN @numDaysChosen = 4 THEN CASE
                    WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                        tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price4DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                    ELSE CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                                YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price4DayInWeek, tcd.Price) * @percentToCalc
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price4DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                                    ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price4DayInWeek, tcd.Price) / 2
                                END
                            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price4DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                        END
                END
            WHEN @numDaysChosen = 5 THEN CASE
                    WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                        tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price5DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                    ELSE CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                                YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price5DayInWeek, tcd.Price) * @percentToCalc
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price5DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                                    ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price5DayInWeek, tcd.Price) / 2
                                END
                            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price5DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                        END
                END
            WHEN @numDaysChosen = 6 THEN CASE
                    WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                        tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price6DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                    ELSE CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                                YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price6DayInWeek, tcd.Price) * @percentToCalc
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN COALESCE(tcd.Price6DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                                    ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price6DayInWeek, tcd.Price) / 2
                                END
                            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(tcd.Price6DayInWeek, tcd.Price)
                        END
                END
            WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR
                tcd.NumOfCharges = 1 THEN tcd.Price
            ELSE CASE
                    WHEN MONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = MONTH(@registrationDate) AND
                        YEAR(tcd.ChargeDate) = YEAR(@registrationDate) THEN CASE
                            WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN tcd.Price * @percentToCalc
                            ELSE CASE
                                    WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN tcd.Price
                                    ELSE tcd.Price / 2
                                END
                        END
                    WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate THEN 0
                    ELSE tcd.Price
                END
        END
        )
    FROM dbo.[TblTeamChargeDef] tcd
    WHERE tcd.teamId = @teamId
```

As you can see, there is a lot of ugly repitition.
There are some variables but they're mostly just booleans that change the behavior, but aren't the core cause of the inflation of code, so they can be ignored, but I can provide if necessary.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried to restructure the query by moving things around, but it doesn't solve the problem. In addition tried implementing a pivot, but I'm not trying to sum anything, just to "rotate" the table so I can more easily access the values

Comment: use `APPLY()` operator to evaluate those common conditions

Comment: Fyi, case is an expression not a statement

Answer (score 3):

You can put the aggregation of the `Price` columns into a `CROSS APPLY`, then use that in the `SUM`.

You can also clean up the `CASE` by using multiplication against the `v.Price` column.

```sql
SELECT
  @priceToPay = SUM(
    v.FinalPrice *
          CASE
            WHEN @AllowWebChargePartial = 0 OR tcd.NumOfCharges = 1
              THEN 1
            WHEN EOMONTH(tcd.ChargeDate) = EOMONTH(@registrationDate)
              THEN
                CASE
                  WHEN @dataExistsPartMonth = 1 THEN @percentToCalc
                  WHEN DAY(@registrationDate) <= 15 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0.5
                END
            WHEN tcd.ChargeDate < @registrationDate
               THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
        )
FROM dbo.TblTeamChargeDef tcd
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(
        CASE @numDaysChosen
          WHEN 1 THEN tcd.Price1DayInWeek
          WHEN 2 THEN tcd.Price2DayInWeek
          WHEN 3 THEN tcd.Price3DayInWeek
          WHEN 4 THEN tcd.Price4DayInWeek
          WHEN 5 THEN tcd.Price5DayInWeek
          WHEN 6 THEN tcd.Price6DayInWeek
        END,
        tcd.Price
      ) AS FinalPrice
) v
WHERE tcd.teamId = @teamId;
```